# No such table error when running a django server from Eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, sqlite, pydev

I'm developing a website using Django. When I run the server through the command prompt like so:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it runs fine, but when I do it from Eclipse (right click on the project -> `Run As...` -> `django project`, I get the following error:

> DatabaseError at /
>   no such table: django_session
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
>   Django Version: 1.3
>   Exception Type: DatabaseError
>   Exception Value:
>   no such table: django_session

Any ideas as to what can cause that? I'm not that proficient in django so I have no clue what file could be causing this - if you need me to post something, please ask here in the comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably Eclipse/PyDev is not able to find the database. Assuming that you use a sqlite3 database, use a full path in the DATABASES settings. Test it via the console and afterwards within Eclipse. That should work ;-)

edit:
As photioionized suggested, the best approach is to put those lines in settings.py

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

and then to

```
SQLITE_3 = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'YOUR DATABASE.DB')
```

SQLITE_3 is now the full path to your sqlite3 database, whereever your django project lives.

Comment: I'm developing with other people (using SVN). Using the full path would not allow them to work properly, wouldn't it?

Comment: There are some simple tricks to specifying something like an absolute path, I put `PROJECT_HOME=os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` and, under the db settings hash `'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_HOME,'database.db'),` in the settings.py file of pretty much every sqlite-based Django project I use... specifies an absolute file path (cross platform) based on the directory your settings.py is in... simplest way of doing everything IMO...

Answer (score 0):

For windows eclipse, It should be full path

```
for e.g. C:\\Abc.db
```

`'\\'` should come in place of single slash.