# Missing Table When Running Django Unittest with Sqlite3

Tags: python, database, django, unit-testing, sqlite

I'm trying to run a unittest with Django 1.3. Normally, I use MySQL as my database backend, but since this is painfully slow to spinup for a single unittest, I'm using Sqlite3.

So to switch to Sqlite3 just for my unittests, in my settings.py I have:

```
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME':'/tmp/database.db',
            'USER'       : '',
            'PASSWORD' : '',
            'HOST'     : '',
        }
    }
```

When I run my unittest with `python manage.py test myapp.Test.test_myfunc`, I get the error:

```
DatabaseError: no such table: django_content_type
```

Googling shows there are a [few](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3) of [possible](http://www.pantz.org/software/sqlite/unabletoopendbsqliteerror.html) [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157152/no-such-table-error-when-running-a-django-server-from-eclipse) for this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636970/sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file), none of which seem applicable to me. I'm not running Apache, so I don't see how permissions would be an issue. The file /tmp/database.db is being created, so /tmp is writable. The app django.contrib.contenttypes is included in my INSTALLED_APPS.

What am I missing?

Edit: I ran into this problem again in Django 1.5, but none of the proposed solutions work.

Answer (score 15):

In Django 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, or 1.8 it *should* be sufficient to use:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
```

It should not be necessary to override `TEST_NAME`<sup>1</sup>, nor to call `syncdb` in order to run tests. As @osa points out, the default with the SQLite engine is to create the test database in memory (`TEST_NAME=':memory:'`). Calling `syncdb` should not be necessary because Django's test framework will do this automatically via a call to `syncdb` or `migrate` depending on the Django version.<sup>2</sup> You can observe this with `manage.py test -v [2|3]`.

Very loosely speaking Django sets up the test environment by:

1. Loading the regular database `NAME` from your `settings.py`
2. Discovering and **constructing** your test classes (`__init__()` is called)
3. Setting the database `NAME` to the value of `TEST_NAME`
4. Running the tests against the database `NAME`

Here's the rub: At step 2, `NAME` is still pointing at your **regular** (non-test) database. If your tests contain class-level queries or queries in `__init__()`, they will be run against the regular database which is likely not what you are expecting. This is identified in [bug #21143](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21143).

Don't do:

```
class BadFooTests(TestCase):
    Foo.objects.all().delete()     # <-- class level queries, and

    def __init__(self):
        f = Foo.objects.create()   # <-- queries in constructor
        f.save()                   #     will run against the production DB

    def test_foo(self):
        # assert stuff
```

since these will be run against the database specified in `NAME`. If `NAME` at this stage points to a valid database (e.g. your production database), the query will run, but may have unintended consequences. If you have overridden `ENGINE` and/or `NAME` such that it does not point to a pre-existing database, an exception will be thrown because the test database has yet to be created:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: yourapp_foo  # Django 1.4
DatabaseError: no such table: yourapp_foo                  # Django 1.5
OperationalError: no such table: yourapp_foo               # Django 1.6+
```

Instead do:

```
class GoodFooTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        f = Foo.objects.create()   # <-- will run against the test DB
        f.save()                   #

    def test_foo(self):
        # assert stuff
```

So, if you are seeing errors, check to see that your tests do not include any queries that might hit the database outside of your test class method definitions.

---

[1] In Django >= 1.7, `DATABASES[alias]['TEST_NAME']` is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-OLD_TEST_NAME) in favour of [`DATABASES[alias]['TEST']['NAME']`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-TEST)
[2] See the `create_test_db()` method in `db/backends/creation.py`

Comment: Just upgraded to 1.7, and now this error happens for `django.contrib.sites`, and the solution you provide does not work.

Comment: In my case, since we were not using in-built migrations feature, just removing migrations folder from app made it work

Answer (score 5):

Having tried all of the above I eventually discovered another reason this can happen:-

**If any of your models are not created by one of your migrations.**

I did some debugging and it seems that Django testing sets up the database by applying all your migrations in order, starting with *001_initial.py*, before trying to SELECT from the tables based on your *models.py*

In my case a table had somehow not been added to the migrations, but added manually, so the full migration set couldn't be properly applied. When I manually fixed the *001_initial.py* migration to create this table the OperationalError went away.

Comment: I had a similar issue, this was especially confusing because the "missing" items were all in my `models.py`, so it was really baffling that they would not be present in the `test_db`. Turned out that I had forgotten to commit some of the migrations from my dev instance when I made the changes.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, too. Turned out that I had to add a TEST_NAME property in the settings.py file to identify the test database properly. It solved the problem for me:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.db'),
            'TEST_NAME': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.db'),
       }
    }
```

Comment: This is very close to my actual solution.

Comment: That was very helpful! If `TEST_NAME` is specified, Django puts the test database in a file instead of keeping it in memory. Thus it was possible for me to suspend the testing process and open the file from another terminal with `sqlite3 test.db`.    I don't think that `NAME` is useful at all for a testing configuration; `TEST_NAME` is probably all we need.

Comment: In fact, I conclude that my tests work with an on-disk database but do not work with an in-memory database.

Comment: I recently ran into this problem again, now on Django 1.5, and this solution doesn't work. I just get the error "no such table myapp_mymodel".

Answer (score 4):

Just to add another case to this:

If you are trying to upgrade to 1.8 from 1.6 (or from a non-migration setup to a migration setup), you might hit this error if you haven't run created migrations.

I had the same problem and had to create migrations so the test runner could use them, which was not intuitive because pre-migrations, the tests would just make a new DB based on doing syncdb, which always worked.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, this also happens if your application is not added to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, for example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
   'myapp'
)
```

Otherwise you get;

```
OperationalError: no such table: myapp_mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

Your table didn't find in database by doing unittest, because unittest inherited *unittest.TestCase*. Wherein don't apply migrations to your database.

If you want to use database with changes from migrations, then you should inherited test case class (for example) from *django.test.TestCase*.

Run `python manage.py test -v 3` and you will see applaying migrations to default testing database.

More information to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Answer (score 0):

Your database is probably empty, it must be setup with all the tables corresponding to your models.  Normally, this would be done by running `python manage.py syncdb` first, to create all your database tables.  The problem is that in your case, when you run syncdb, python will not see that you are running a test so it will try to setup tables in your MySQL database instead.

To get around this, temporarily change

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
```

to

```
if True:
```

Then run `python manage.py syncdb` to setup the sqlite database tables.  Now that everything is setup, you can put back in `if 'test'...` and everything should run smoothly. However you probably want to move your database out of the `/tmp` directory: django needs to re-use the same database every time you run your tests, otherwise you'll have to create database tables before every test.

Note that if you add new models, you will need to repeat this procedure to create the new tables in sqlite.  If you add new fields to an existing model, you will need to manually add columns to your sqlite database using the sqlite interface and `ALTER TABLE...`, or do it automatically using a tool like [South.](http://south.aeracode.org/)

Comment: I doubt this will work. Django destroys the test database after each run, so if you're correct, I'd need to do a syncdb prior to each run...

Comment: It DOES work. The test-Sqlite database is [in-memory by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#the-test-database), so there are no files to destroy after a test. The file you create with syncdb acts merely as a template for the in-memory test database. A syncdb is only necessary when the database structure changes.

Comment: A most ridiculous construct!  `if True` will always execute, so why waste your time checking it at all?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the follwoing lines after test database definition:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('syncdb', migrate=True)
```

Comment: This does not work for 1.7 (and probably not for >= 1.5)

Answer (score 0):

For those who tried all possible ways but still stuck in this:

Since our test code is still running in other machine but not mine, I tried to:

- Create a new virtual-env. (so isolate the affect of apps)
- Clone a new repository. (isolate the affect of ignored files)
- Set in `settings` to use `sqlite3` instead of `psql` (isolate the affect of database, and database settings)
- Check `env` variables, and `.env` file (since I used `foreman`)

None of those helped. Until I:

1. Create a new account on my machine. (So start clean)
2. Clone the repository.
3. Run tests -> Success
4. Go back to my main account.
5. Open a new terminal (kill current `tmux` server if you're using them).
6. Run tests -> Success

So this is not a real answer for your question, since I don't know what was wrong and how it fixed, just another suggestion that you may try.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that will get here, searching for why Django keeps creating a database regardless of the `--keepdb` option. Why it says `Using existing test database for alias 'default'`, but then runs a bunch of `CREATE TABLE` statements.

If you don't set a [DATABASES > default > TEST > NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEST_NAME) setting, Django will try to use in memory database, and it wont be kept, so set this and override a defaults.

You can make it like this:

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'data', 'db.dev.sqlite3'),
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'data', 'db.test.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I was caused by a previous branch code, so I fixed it removing the pyc files in my projects:

```
find -regex .*pyc | xargs sudo rm
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons why this error can occur, for me it had to do with hackish data-migrations.

These data-migrations did some operations on a model that required a field that was not created yet.

E.g.

```
0001_accounts.py {create the model User}
0002_accounts.py {{for user in User.objects.all(): user.save() }
0003_accounts.py {add a new column to User object}
```

It fails on 0002 as it tries to save the user object but doesn't have the new column yet.

To debug:

```
switch to an empty database
run python manage.py migrate
```

See where it stops, that is probably the hackish datamigration you'd want to uncomment.